# Laravel display warning before rate limit lockout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a custom rate limiting rule in my `RouteServiceProvider.php` which looks like so;

```php
protected function configureRateLimiting()
{
    RateLimiter::for('example', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perHour(5)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip())->response(function () {
            return response()->view('auth.login', [
                'error' =>
                    'You have exceeded the maximum number of login attempts. ' .
                    'Your account has been blocked for security reasons.',
                'page' => 'login',
            ], 422);
        });
    });
}
```

This locks out the user after 5 attempts in an hour.

I would like to add a warning though after 2 attempts aswell, something like `you have had two failed login attempts. If you continue entering an incorrect password your account will be locked.`

I have tried the following in my login controller, but it doesnt work;

```php
if (RateLimiter::remaining(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip(), 2)) {
    RateLimiter::hit(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());

    return view('auth.login')->with([
        'error' => 'You have had two failed login attempts. If you continue entering an incorrect password your account will be locked.',
        'page' => 'login'
    ]);
}
```

Is this possible? I cant find anything regarding this.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the rate limiter information will be pass into the reponse headers `X-RateLimit-Limit` and `X-RateLimit-Remaining` which you may or may not be able to extract

It would be much easier to manually interact with `RateLimiter` class and [manually increment the limiter](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/rate-limiting#manually-incrementing-attempts), this way, you can return the remaining attempt and all the other information.

here's a basic example;

add the class `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;`

then manually invoke `hit` and count the remaining attempts,

```
Route::get('/whatever-login-route', function( Request $request ) {
    
    $key = 'login-limit:'.$request->ip;

    //RateLimiter::resetAttempts( $key ); // resetting attempts
    //RateLimiter::clear( $key ); // resetting attempts and lockout timer

    return [
        'hit' => RateLimiter::hit($key, 3600),
        'remaining' => RateLimiter::remaining($key, 5),
        'reset_at' => RateLimiter::availableIn($key)
    ];

});
```

This is just a basic example, but as you can see, in your login controller, you can pass the `remaining` or `hit` value and do your warning message after 2 hits, and return an error message with 429 header if the `remaining` value is less than 1 or `hit` value is more than 5.

Example usage in your case

```
$key = optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip(); 
$hit = RateLimiter::hit($key, 3600 ); // 2nd parameter is the value lockout timer in seconds
$remaining = RateLimiter::remaining($key, 5) // 2nd parameter is the number of allowed attempts in lockout define above

if ( $hit == 2 ) { // if ( $remaining == 3 )

    return view('auth.login')->with([
        'error' => 'You have had two failed login attempts. If you continue entering an incorrect password your account will be locked.',
        'page' => 'login'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work ... I have put in the following in my login controller just as a test `$key = 'login-limit:'.$request->ip; $count = RateLimiter::retriesLeft($key, 5);` but when printing the `$count` it just stays at 5 even though the lockout functionality works perfect

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have tried

Comment: I have updated my answer, your attempt means 2 hit per 60 seconds as you did not define 2nd parameter on `hit`